# Host nancy in existing mvc 4 site null reference exception

Tags: c#, nancy

I'm trying to set up Nancy to handle certain routes inside an existing MVC 4 website.  I want to use the Razor template engine in both the existing site and Nancy.  My web configs are as follows:

**Root web.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=152368
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup></configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-Mvcsample-20140828192644;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-Mvcsample-20140828192644.mdf" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  <add key="webPages:Enabled" value="false" /></appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" />
      <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1">

      <buildProviders>
        <add extension=".cshtml" type="Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor.BuildProviders.NancyCSharpRazorBuildProvider, Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor.BuildProviders" />
        <add extension=".vbhtml" type="Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor.BuildProviders.NancyVisualBasicRazorBuildProvider, Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor.BuildProviders" />
      </buildProviders></compilation>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
    <profile defaultProvider="DefaultProfileProvider">
        <providers>
        <add name="DefaultProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultProfileProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </profile>
      <membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
        <providers>
           <add name="DefaultMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
        </providers>
      </membership>
      <roleManager defaultProvider="DefaultRoleProvider">
        <providers>
        <add name="DefaultRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultRoleProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <!--
            If you are deploying to a cloud environment that has multiple web server instances,
            you should change session state mode from "InProc" to "Custom". In addition,
            change the connection string named "DefaultConnection" to connect to an instance
            of SQL Server (including SQL Azure and SQL  Compact) instead of to SQL Server Express.
      -->
    <sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">
         <providers>
          <add name="DefaultSessionProvider"  type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" />
      </providers>
      </sessionState>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
     <handlers>
        <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
        <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
        <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
           <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*."   verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*."   verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />

    </handlers>
      <!--<httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />--></system.webServer>
      <runtime>
       <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
         <dependentAssembly>
         <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
         </dependentAssembly>
        <dependentAssembly>
           <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
          <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
         </dependentAssembly>
         <dependentAssembly>
          <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
         </dependentAssembly>
      </assemblyBinding>
     </runtime>
    <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    </entityFramework>
       <location path="NancyTest" >
          <system.web>




            <!--<httpHandlers>
                <add verb="*" type="Nancy.Hosting.Aspnet.NancyHttpRequestHandler" path="*" />
            </httpHandlers>-->
        </system.web>

        <system.webServer>
            <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
            <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
            <handlers>
                <add name="Nancy" verb="*" type="Nancy.Hosting.Aspnet.NancyHttpRequestHandler" path="*" />
            </handlers>
        </system.webServer>
        <system.web.webPages.razor>
            <pages pageBaseType="Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor.NancyRazorViewBase">
                <namespaces>
                    <add namespace="Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor" />
                </namespaces>
            </pages>
        </system.web.webPages.razor>
    </location>
</configuration>
```

**Child web.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <configuration>
        <configSections>

            <section name="razor" type="Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor.RazorConfigurationSection, Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor" />
     </configSections>

    <appSettings>
       <add key="webPages:Enabled" value="false" />
    </appSettings>
       <razor disableAutoIncludeModelNamespace="false">
        <assemblies>
            <add assembly="NancyTest" />
            <add assembly="Nancy" />
        </assemblies>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor" />
      </namespaces>

  </razor>
  </configuration>
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>NancyTest</title>

    <style type="text/css">

        body {
            text-align: center;
        }

    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <!--<img src="~/Content/nancy-logo.png" alt="Nancy logo" />--><br />
    This view was rendered using the Nancy Razor view engine
</body>
</html>
```

When I navigate to the Nancy route I get the following error message:

```
Nancy.RequestExecutionException: Oh noes! ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Nancy.ViewEngines.DefaultViewCache.GetOrAdd[TCompiledView](ViewLocationResult viewLocationResult, Func`2 valueFactory)
   at Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor.RazorViewEngine.GetOrCompileView(ViewLocationResult viewLocationResult, IRenderContext renderContext, Assembly referencingAssembly, Type passedModelType)
   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute5[T0,T1,T2,T3,T4,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3, T4 arg4)
   at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , RazorViewEngine , ViewLocationResult , IRenderContext , Assembly , Object )
   at Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor.RazorViewEngine.GetViewInstance(ViewLocationResult viewLocationResult, IRenderContext renderContext, Assembly referencingAssembly, Object model)
   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute5[T0,T1,T2,T3,T4,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3, T4 arg4)
   at Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor.RazorViewEngine.<>c__DisplayClass27.b__26(Stream stream)
   at Nancy.Responses.MaterialisingResponse.PreExecute(NancyContext context)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Nancy.NancyEngine.InvokeOnErrorHook(NancyContext context, ErrorPipeline pipeline, Exception ex)
```

What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: is that the complete stack trace? If not we'd like to see it all.

Comment: Yes this is the complete trace.

Comment: I have this funn feeling it is because you named your project NancyTest. Can you try not having "Nancy" in your name.

Comment: @Phill I still get the same error even after renaming.

Comment: Any luck with this?  I am having the same problem with Nancy 0.23.2/MVC 5.2.

Comment: @ProfNimrod No luck on this at all.

Comment: I think I found the problem.  I think that when creating the View, it cannot find the _Layout.cshtml that was in a different folder.  I also had trouble with having partial views in a different folder.  When I put all the View elements under the same folder (with no sub folders) it seemed to work OK. (This was with MVC 5.2)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that Nancy does not likes paths like "/views/shared/_layout.cshtml", and i gt Null Reference exception until i changed layout path to "views/shared/_layout.cshtml".
It even was documented somewhere in Nacy Fx docs, that paths convention is not same as for MVC and ~/ or "/" paths does not work..